# three.js create a rectangular tube with rounded edges

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create a tube in three.js in the shape of a rectangle with rounded edges. The tube itself should be circular.

The code I have so far creates a ugly rectangle.

Can anyone help me?

```
var renderer;
var camera;
var scene;

function initScene()
{
    //Scene setup
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var width = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0].offsetWidth;
    var height = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0].offsetHeight;
    //Camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 260);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, -100);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    //Light
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    light.position.set(0.0001, 0.0001, 260);
    scene.add(light);
    //Render canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")[0];
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);

    //Create tube
    var path = new THREE.CurvePath();
    path.add(new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(-10.0, -10.0, 0.0), new THREE.Vector3(10.0, -10.0, 0.0)));
    path.add(new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(10.0, -10.0, 0.0), new THREE.Vector3(10.0, 10.0, 0.0)));
    path.add(new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(10.0, 10.0, 0.0), new THREE.Vector3(-10.0, 10.0, 0.0)));
    path.add(new THREE.LineCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(-10.0, 10.0, 0.0), new THREE.Vector3(-10.0, -10.0, 0.0)));
    //Create geometry and material
    var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(path, 10, 1.0, 10, true);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFFFFFF, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
    //Start animation
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //Window resize listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", windowResize, false);
    //Mobile flip
    window.addEventListener("change", windowResize, false);
}

function windowResize()
{
    var height = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0].offsetHeight;
    var width = document.getElementsByClassName("scene")[0].offsetWidth;
    var aspect = width / height;
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

function animate()
{
    //Render scene
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    //Request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

This code gets me this:
[Bad rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd8c0.png)

This is what I want:
[Good rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXfsg.png)

Comment: I believe that one of the shapes in this example https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shape#webgl_geometry_shapes is the one you want.

Comment: I'll have a look thx

Comment: You should extrude a shape to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is [ExtrudeBufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeBufferGeometry)

Please look into this example: [https://threejs.org/...webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=shape#webgl_geometry_extrude_shapes)

**Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/vhgnyt4z/**

[image: extrude tube along some path with three.js]

And here is the code:

```js
let renderer;
let camera;
let controls;

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(54, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xfefefe));
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.x = -2;
camera.position.y = 0.5;
camera.position.z = 10;
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

// white spotlight shining from the side, casting a shadow
let spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 2.5, 25, Math.PI / 6);
spotLight.position.set(9, 10, 1);
scene.add(spotLight);
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x202020); // soft white light
scene.add(light);

// example starts here
let gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(4, 4);
scene.add(gridHelper);

var length = 0.5,
    width = 0.5;

var r = 0.5;
var w = 1;
var l = 2;

var extrudeShape = new THREE.Shape();
extrudeShape.moveTo(-w + r, -l);
extrudeShape.absarc(-w + r, -l + r, r, -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, true);
extrudeShape.lineTo(-w, l - r);
extrudeShape.absarc(-w + r, l - r, r, Math.PI, Math.PI / 2, true);
extrudeShape.lineTo(w - r, l);
extrudeShape.absarc(w - r, l - r, r, Math.PI / 2, 0, true);
extrudeShape.lineTo(w, -l + r);
extrudeShape.absarc(w - r, -l + r, r, 0, -Math.PI / 2, true);

var wallThickness = 0.2;
var wi = w - wallThickness;
var li = l - wallThickness;
var ri = r - wallThickness / 2;
var hole = new THREE.Path();
hole.moveTo(-wi + ri, -li);
hole.absarc(-wi + ri, -li + ri, ri, Math.PI, -Math.PI / 2, false);
hole.lineTo(wi - ri, -li);
hole.absarc(wi - ri, -li + ri, ri, -Math.PI / 2, 0, false);
hole.lineTo(wi, li - ri);
hole.absarc(wi - ri, li - ri, ri, 0, Math.PI / 2, false);
hole.lineTo(-wi + ri, li);
hole.absarc(-wi + ri, li - ri, ri, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, false);
extrudeShape.holes.push(hole);

var curve = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(
    new THREE.Vector3(-10 / 5, 0, 0),
    new THREE.Vector3(-5 / 5, 15 / 5, -2),
    new THREE.Vector3(20 / 5, 15 / 5, -1),
    new THREE.Vector3(10 / 5, 0, 0)
);

var extrudeSettings = {
    steps: 32,
    depth: 1,
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelThickness: 0.1,
    bevelSize: 0.1,
    bevelSegments: 1,
    curveSegments: 32,
    extrudePath: curve
};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(extrudeShape, extrudeSettings);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

let animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```